# Haskell: arrow precedence with function arguments

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, arguments, operator-precedence

I'm a *relatively* experienced Haskell programmer with a few hours of experience, so the answer might be obvious.

After watching A taste of Haskell, I got lost when Simon explained how the append `(++)` function *really* works with its arguments.

So, [here's the part where he talks about this](https://youtu.be/jLj1QV11o9g?t=36m37s).

First, he says that `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` can be understood as a function which gets two lists as arguments, and returns a list after the last arrow). However, he adds that *actually*, something like this happens: `(++) :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a])`, the function takes only *one* argument and returns a function.

I'm not sure to understand how the returned function closure gets the first list as it expects one argument as well.

On the next slide of the presentation, we have the following implementation:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

If I think that (++) receives two arguments and return a list, this piece of code along with the recursion is clear enough.

If we consider that `(++)` receives only one argument and returns a list, *where does* `ys` *come from? Where is the returned function ?*

Comment: Look up _currying_: in most functional programming language there is no such a thing as a function taking more than one argument. A "binary function" is a technically incorrect term for a function taking _one_ argument (the "first" one) and returning a function. This returned function takes _one_ argument (the "second" one), and finally returns the result. E.g. `(++) [1,2]` is a function that can be applied to `[4,5]` to produce `[1,2,4,5]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to understanding this is that all haskell functions only take 1 argument at most, it's just that the implicit parentheses in the type signature and syntax sugar make it appear as if there are more arguments.  To use `++` as an example, the following transformations are all equivalent

```
xs ++ ys = ...
(++) xs ys = ...
(++) xs = \ys -> ...
(++) = \xs -> (\ys -> ...)
(++) = \xs ys -> ...
```

Another quick example:

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList = map (*2)
```

Here we have a function of one argument `doubleList` without any explicit arguments.  It would have been equivalent to write

```
doubleList x = map (*2) x
```

Or any of the following

```
doubleList = \x -> map (*2) x
doubleList = \x -> map (\y -> y * 2) x
doubleList x = map (\y -> y * 2) x
doubleList = map (\y -> y * 2)
```

The first definition of `doubleList` is written in what is commonly called point-free notation, so called because in the mathematical theory backing it the arguments are referred to as "points", so point-free is "without arguments".

A more complex example:

```
func = \x y z -> x * y + z
func = \x -> \y z -> x * y + z
func x = \y z -> x * y + z
func x = \y -> \z -> x * y + z
func x y = \z -> x * y + z
func x y z = x * y + z
```

Now if we wanted to completely remove all references to the arguments we can make use of the `.` operator which performs function composition:

```
func x y z = (+) (x * y) z    -- Make the + prefix
func x y = (+) (x * y)        -- Now z becomes implicit
func x y = (+) ((*) x y)      -- Make the * prefix
func x y = ((+) . ((*) x)) y  -- Rewrite using composition
func x = (+) . ((*) x)        -- Now y becomes implicit
func x = (.) (+) ((*) x)      -- Make the . prefix
func x = ((.) (+)) ((*) x)    -- Make implicit parens explicit
func x = (((.) (+)) . (*)) x  -- Rewrite using composition
func = ((.) (+)) . (*)        -- Now x becomes implicit
func = (.) ((.) (+)) (*)      -- Make the . prefix
```

So as you can see there are lots of different ways to write a particular function with a varying number of explicit "arguments", some of which are very readable (i.e. `func x y z = x * y + z`) and some which are just a jumble of symbols with little meaning (i.e. `func = (.) ((.) (+)) (*)`)

Comment: Alright, so I can think of functions being _aliases_ for lambda functions. Arguments aren't passed but sort of _filled/replaced_ as per : `add = \x y -> x + y`, `add 3 4` <=> `(\x y -> x + y) 3 4`

Comment: Yet, I read that the point-free style is the most preferred one. Is there any way to write your last `func =` line with high-order functions ?

Comment: @D.Naesuko Point-free style is only preferred when it looks clearer. That is only some times the case when you remove *one* function argument, and *rarely* the case when you remove more than one.

Answer (score 2):

#### You are confused about how *[Function Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)* works.

Consider the following function definitions of `(++)`.

**Takes two arguments, produces one list:**

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

**Takes one argument, produces a function taking one list and producing a list:**

```
(++) :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a])
(++) []     = id
(++) (x:xs) = (x :) . (xs ++)
```

If you look closely, these functions will always produce the same output. By removing the second parameter, we have changed the return type from `[a]` to `[a] -> [a]`.

- If we supply two parameters to `(++)` we get a result of type `[a]`
- If we supply only one parameter we get a result of type `[a] -> [a]`

This is called function currying. We don't need to provide all the arguments to a function with multiple arguments. If we supply fewer then the total number of arguments, instead of getting a "concrete" result (`[a]`) we get a function as a result which can take the remaining parameters (`[a] -> [a]`).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help.  First let's write it without operator notation which might be confusing.

```
append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
append [] ys = ys
append (x:xs) ys = x : append xs ys
```

We can apply one argument at a time:

```
appendEmpty :: [a] -> [a]
appendEmpty = append []
```

we could equivalently could have written that

```
appendEmpty ys = ys
```

from the first equation.

If we apply a non-empty first argument:

```
-- Since 1 is an Int, the type gets specialized.
appendOne :: [Int] -> [Int]
appendOne = append (1:[])
```

we could have equivalently have written that

```
appendOne ys = 1 : append [] ys
```

from the second equation.